# Keep variable regardless of re-render without useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `point1`,`point2` variable which is used to draw the dots in `canvas` object.

I am trying some tests.

For example,

- test1

  - `changePoint1()` is called, tha canvas itself is re-rendered, so it's not good method.
- test2

  - `changePoint2()` is called, the canvas is not re-rendered, but when re-render is called from somewhere else, this variable is not kept.

Is there any variable keeping method which doesn't call re-render and keep the variable regardless of re-render? (maybe like `static` variable?)

```
const ImagePreview = () =>{
    const [point1,setPoint1] = [0,0]; // test1
    var point2  = [10,10]; //test2
    
    const changePoint1(){
      setPoint1([10,10]) 
    }

    const changePoint2(){
      point2 = [20,20];
    }

    const rewriteCanvas(){
     // draw point1,point2 in canvas
    }

    return <canvas></canvas>
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of changing the variable value if you don't want to render the updated state? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Note that in test1 the already-mounted canvas instance will not be remounted. As in, any  canvas internal state will be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ref. See [Referencing Values with Refs](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs) and [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

```js
const ref = useRef(/* initial value */);
// assign to or read ref.current later on without causing rerenders...
```