# callback for useRef() react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `useRef` to keep variable avoiding re-render.
(`useState` automatically re-render the item).

However now I want to have callback like `useState()` for example

```
const tempRef = useRef(1)

useEffect(() => {
// I want callback when tempRef.current is changed.
},[tempRef.current]);
```

Is there any good way??

Comment: Just like with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76259013/1048572), it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with this. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Why are you even using React?

Comment: You cannot use `useEffect` or any other React hook, since an effect only runs after the component has been rendered. Which, for some reason, you want to avoid. So just call your callback every time when you set the value of the ref.

Comment: @Bergi  Thank you, I am just practicing the `Rect`, my purpose is do something when useRef.current data is changed.

Comment: What I want to do is not using `useEffect, I want to know the equivalent to `useEffect` of `useState()`, for `useRef()`

Comment: If you're only practising, then [better avoid refs](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#best-practices-for-refs).

Comment: It seems you're comparing react with something else, please provide your use case to understand what you're going to do.

Comment: The execution timing of useEffect is called after each rendering and re-render of the component. During the execution process, the content in deps will be compared shallowly, and the incoming function will be executed only if there is a change. So i think it is impossible for you to avoid re-render and trigger useEffect to re-execute.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read about `useRef()` more, I decided not to use `useRef()`. What I want to do is keeping value regardless of component lifecycle, So, I made another class which is never re-rendered and used static value in it.